# How can make responsive menu using html+css with input checkbox?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When the checkbox is clicked, `margin:left` of `nav` should increases and enters the screen. When clicked again, it should decrease and go out of the screen. It doesn't work like that. What's the problem with my code?

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="res-nav">
<label for="res-nav"><i class="fa fa-reorder" style="font-size:36px"></i></label>
```

**Style**

```
 body label {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin-left:-100px; 
    margin-top: -115px; 
    z-index:99;
}

nav{
    margin-left:-130px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

#res-nav:checked ~ nav {
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Comment: You understand how it is supposed to work? Where exactly is your `<nav>` element?

Comment: Check my answer below. Your class selector is incorrect. @Ahmet

Comment: `nav` in `body` tag. You asked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
label {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin-left:-100px; 
    margin-top: -115px; 
    z-index:99;
}

nav{
    margin-left:-9999px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    background:tomato;
    max-width:100vw;
}

#res-nav:checked ~ nav {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="res-nav">
<label for="res-nav"><i class="fa fa-reorder" style="font-size:36px"></i>s</label>
<nav>Navbar</nav>
```

Comment: My code is exactly same with yours. But I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: There are some changes made. But your exemple didnt have the <nav> element after the input

Comment: Ok i understand. By writing ~ in CSS the element followed by the sign must be after the first element. <checkbox> then <nav>

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```css
.nav{
    margin-left:-120px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#res-nav:checked ~ .nav {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="res-nav">
<label for="res-nav" class="nav">
 <i class="fa fa-reorder" style="font-size:36px">Hello</i>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this suit your needs? Rather than using margin, as you can see, I used positions, if you'd like to be able to scroll on your nav tag, I guess you could always use overflow within a nested div?

I set the min-height to that height because vh doesn't work in older browsers, so it's a simple enough backup solution. You could also use some JS to calculate the height that you want it to be to the exact pixel, but using no JS whatsoever, I think this is a good enough solution?

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

body label {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin-left:-100px; 
    margin-top: -115px; 
    z-index:99;
}

#res-nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}

nav{
    position: fixed;
    left: -9999px;
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 9999px;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

nav * {
  color: white;
}

#res-nav:checked ~ nav {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="res-nav">
  <label for="res-nav"><i class="fa fa-reorder" style="font-size:36px"></i></label>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">hello world</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```